# Is it true that students from European countries have had many more advanced courses in mathematics when they arrive to Grad school in the US?

Tags: graduate-school, mathematics

This question is inspired by what Steven Krantz wrote in his book "A mathematicians survival guide."

> If you are an American student, educated in the USA, then you may 
>   find that the international students in your graduate program appear to be 
>   way ahead of you. First of all, students in Italy, France, and other European 
>   countries often specialize much earlier than we do in the United States. They 
>   have had many more advanced math courses than you will have had. [I was 
>   once told that a typical Italian math student graduating from college will 
>   have taken 22 year-long math courses. I have not had 22 year-long math 
>   courses in my entire life.]

If this is not true, then in your experience, from which countries/universities do you get the most advanced graduate student?

Comment: I have to admit that the introduction of the bachelor degree, following the [Bologna process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna_Process), spoiled a lot the quality of the mathematical preparation in Italy, but having taught to many students coming from different countries (but not the US) both at the bachelor and master's levels, I recognize that Italian students have generally a better mathematical background (but in many cases I consider it still too low).

Comment: I have read that Scuola Normale Superiore offers a pretty strong program in Mathematics. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, the Scuola Normale Superiore di Pisa (SNS) is excellent: I met several graduates from the SNS, and they showed really excellent (and I mean, _excellent_) preparation, both in mathematics and physics. But SNS is really not for the faint of heart, or at least, it used to be: I heard that they had to lower a bit the standards too.

Comment: Western european students are bloody amateur mathematicians when you have seen people from the good (high) schools in Russia or Persia. ;-)

Comment: Depends on the county and university. At my university measure theory is a 3rd semester compulsory course. In the US it's not even required at most universities.

Comment: @Supermario yeah its good, only Cambridge, Oxford, Imperial, ETH, ecole polytechnique, and bonn university are better in europe

Comment: Relevant background: comparing MA/BA/PhD programs in the US vs Europe: http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/9505/31917

Comment: My impression is that the German system and the US system don't match up year for year, in the sense that a German STEM student of the same age will have done more math than the US counterpart.

Comment: @TryingToGraduate which university are you referring to?

Comment: Technische Universität Dresden

Comment: I once worked with an Austrian graduate engineer at a USA university who could not integrate an exponential. So generally speaking I don't think this is true anymore.

Comment: @DBB Or he specialized too early to learn how to integrate an exponential?

Comment: that is calculus 1. But I get what Stephen Krantz is saying. Greek engineers especially of a certain age in my experience were PDE wizards. I would put it as for a long time USA research was better funded so people there got good at playing with expensive toys. Euro researchers had to be better at paper science to stay competitive. Nowadays with EU mobility and multinational research centres I feel this is no longer the case.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, it is a important to note that there is a vast amount of variation between institutions and individuals, so generalizations are not terribly helpful here.

That said, historically there have indeed been differences in the philosophy and organization of European and American approaches to education. European education has tended to put more emphasis on *knowledge*, where American education has tended to put more emphasis on *creativity* and *communication*.  As a result, many European students are already specializing in high school, while many American students are *required* to remain generalists until university and may in fact still be taking classes outside their "focus" all the way through the end of their undergraduate studies.

This does not, however, provide any clear advantage to one group or the other when it comes to doing a Ph.D.  At the doctoral level, one needs both knowledge and also creativity and the ability to communicate well with colleagues. Thus, while students educated in one tradition are more likely to enter graduate school being able to prove Urysohn's Lemma, students educated in the other tradition are more likely to be able to effectively communicate why that proof is interesting.

In short: the word "appear" is in the original quote for a reason.

Comment: _American education has tended to put more emphasis on creativity and communication_ [citation needed]

Comment: @DanRomik jeff schmidht, book disciplined mind.

Comment: @DanRomik Consider the prevalence of [core curricula and distribution requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum#Core_curriculum) at US institutions vs. "focusing" requirements such as the [A-levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCE_Advanced_Level) in the UK